# How to silence the detailed output logs of `npm install` command?

Tags: node.js, npm, command-line-arguments, npm-install, node-modules

This might be a silly question, but I really wanted to know is there any way to see only the errors / success logs while running the `npm install` command by removing details of entire package installation details.

Is there any helpful optional arguments which we can pass along with `npm install` command which will give only the minimal logs without detailed description of each every dependency installation ?

Answer (score 11):

Yeah, of course, there is.

**Try**

```
npm install -s (or --silent)
```

or

```
npm install -q (or --quiet)
```

Comment: What is the exact difference between quiet and silent? Acc. to me, silent won't show any logs while quiet will show. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I don't see neither `silent` nor `quiet` in [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-install), are you sure any of them work?

Comment: this is not working in npm 8 at least.

Comment: See an [updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73640085/6322589) below for npm version 8

Comment: This answer should still work according to [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/logging?v=true#aliases)

Answer (score 9):

See [this](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/2040) issue on github.

If you are lazy (pick one):

1. Use `--silent` flag.
2. Set logging level: `npm config set loglevel warn`. This will print warnings and errors.

Comment: If too many warnings try `npm config set loglevel error` followed by `npm install`. Allows installing while showing only errors.

Answer (score 5):

In [npm version 8](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/logging) you can pass the log level argument:

```
npm install --loglevel {level}
```

where `{level}` is one of

- "silent"
- "error"
- "warn"
- "notice"
- "http"
- "timing"
- "info"
- "verbose"
- "silly"

Answer (score 0):

Use  `--no-warnings` flag with npm installl